# Passing unicode to stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
usp_InsertQAnswers accepting parameters, @sq int null,  @rnd int null,  @name nvarchar(50)
```

I am trying to pass unicode (Chinese characters) from a php form with

```
$sql = "Execute usp_InsertQAnswers '".$sq."', '".$rnd."', N'".$pa_name."'";

$result=odbc_exec($con,$sql);
```

the inserted 'name' will show symbols like åŠ‰å¾³ç…Œ7

if I call the stored procedure in SMSS using `usp_InsertQAnswers 'number','number',N'chinese word'`; it works perfectly

How do I pass Chinese characters from the form to the stored procedure?

Comment: You don't need to use `N` prefix if you're using parameters

Comment: tried without the N, but won't work. In SMSS, I need to add "N" for the sp to work

Comment: You missed "if you're using parameters" - which is the safe way to interact with SQL Server from code - as opposed to concatenated strings like you are doing.

Comment: Of course it won't works since you're not parameterizing your query. That will leads you to many issues, that's one of them a long side with SQL Injection.

Comment: how do i parametise my query?

Comment: $stmt = odbc_prepare($con,'Execute usp_InsertQAnswers(?,?,?)');
 $result = odbc_execute($stmt,array($sq,$rnd,$pa_name));

tried this with error:Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Invalid Descriptor Index. Is this the way to do it, thanks

Comment: $stmt = odbc_prepare($con,'exec usp_InsertQAnswers ?,?,?');
 $result = odbc_execute($stmt,array('33','33','你好嗎')); tried this, works but chinese word inserted as symbols